# Unity not playing full animation and only playing segments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was working on a game in unity, and I needed some animations so I made this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator m_animator;
    
    void Start()
    {
        m_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Chop");
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Idle");
                m_animator.SetTrigger("Run");
            }
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Chop");
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Idle");
                m_animator.SetTrigger("Run");
            }
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Chop");
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Idle");
                m_animator.SetTrigger("Run");
            }
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Chop");
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Idle");
                m_animator.SetTrigger("Run");
            }
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Chop");
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Idle");
                m_animator.SetTrigger("Run");
            }
            else if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Run");
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Idle");
                m_animator.SetTrigger("Chop");
            }
            else
            {
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Run");
                m_animator.ResetTrigger("Chop");
                m_animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
            }
        }

}
```

It works, but it only plays a little bit of the animation before cutting and either restarting the animation, or going onto another one. How can that be fixed?

Comment: have a look at the animator window while its playing. You'll see a bunch of states and arrows (transitions). If you select them there's quite a bit of tweaking you can do. Often animations blends into other or have exit times etc... Try and play around with all of that its a nice too thats very visual.

Comment: Have you tried to rather use `GetKeyDown` in order to set the trigger only **ONCE** instead of **each and every frame**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a problem that comes from the `exit time` of the animations transition. I suggest you to go in the Animator Controller then click on your transitions in the Animation Graph and uncheck "Has Exit Time".

If you want to keep the exit times so you have to adjust each transition time to work well with the animation duration.

[image: Has Exit time]

Keep me informed about the result !

Comment: Now the animations are working again! Thank you!